# How to assign values to a column using multiindex filter?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I can't update the values on a column when I filter using a multiindex.

```
features_complete_new_index['ev_2'] = 1

features_complete_new_index.loc[true_positives_indexes,:].ev_2 = True

features_complete_new_index.loc[false_negatives_indexes,:].ev2 = False

features_complete_new_index.ev_2.value_counts()
```

**Output**

```
Out[20]:
1    8176700
Name: ev_2, dtype: int64
```

**Expected output**

```
1 7000000
True 1000000
False 17670000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect Pandas is giving you a **SettingwithCopyWarning** warning. There is a [very good article](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/) that explains the risk of doing "chained assignment".

The core problem is that when you write :

`features_complete_new_index.loc[true_positives_indexes,:]`

**you don't know if Pandas is working with the original data or a copy of it**.

So when writing :

```
features_complete_new_index.loc[true_positives_indexes,:].ev_2 = True
```

You might be assigning True to a *copy* of your dataframe.

The solution is to do it in a **single loc operation** :

```
features_complete_new_index.loc[true_positives_indexes,'ev_2'] = True
```

It is very well explained in the article.

Comment: Thanks for this! Yes, the solution was to use features_complete_new_index.loc[true_positives_indexes,'ev_2'] = True